# Android Linear Layout Split Screen with Scrollview

Tags: android, split, scrollview, android-linearlayout

The following is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#F4F2F2"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Notes:"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/notetext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
        </EditText>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/mImageView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
          android:src="@drawable/picframe" android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

      </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#FFFFFF"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically I have 3 linear layouts
the first one is the size of the whole screen
the other two are inside the first and split the screen into two
the right hand layout displays a bitmap  which works fine
The left hand layout displays a notes box

this all works fine but I want to make the left side scrollable so if you enter notes more than the height of the screen you can keep going and scroll down to see the rest

problem is it all works fine until I add the scrollview as above

the notes editbox and label disappear and cant be seen
If I remove the scrollview they come back

Any ideas where im going wrong?
As always any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes you need to do in your xml
i.e. removing background color from scrollview and shifting linear layout background to scrollview and removing layout weight from linear layout and setting width as match_parent

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#F4F2F2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#F4F2F2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Notes:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/notetext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textColor="#000000" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case equal weight is needed for child ScrollView and LinearLayout and set Scoll data to center of ScrollView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F4F2F2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Notes:"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/notetext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            </EditText>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/picframe"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try, you don't need to give `0dp` to your child `LinearLayout`.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F4F2F2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
```